# is any method to approximate the softmax probability under special conditions?

Tags: machine-learning, math, deep-learning, softmax

I'm trying to find approach to compute the softmax probability without using exp().

assume that:

```
target: to compute f(x1, x2, x3) = exp(x1)/[exp(x1)+exp(x2)+exp(x3)]

conditions:

    1. -64 < x1,x2,x3 < 64

    2. result is just kept 3 desimal places.
```

is there any way to find a polynomial to approximately represent the result under such conditions?

Comment: You could approximate `exp` in `softmax` with piece-wise linear functions (see [here](https://vijaychan.github.io/Publications/2018_softmax.pdf)), another possibilities [are in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984440/approximate-ex). It depends what you're after and why you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

**My understanding of Softmax probability**

The output of neural networks (NN) is not very discriminating. For example if I have 3 classes, for the correct class say NN output may be some value `a` and for others `b,c` such that `a>b, a>c`. But if we do the softmax trick, after transformation firstly `a+b+c = 1` which makes it interpretable as probability. Secondly, `a>>>b, a>>>c` and so we are now much more confident.

**So how to go further**

To get the first advantage, it is sufficient to use

```
f(x1)/[f(x1)+f(x2)+f(x3)]
(equation 1)
```

for any function `f(x)`

Softmax chooses `f(x)=exp(x)`. But as you are not comfortable with `exp(x)`, you can choose say `f(x)=x^2`.

I give some plots below which have profile similar to exponential and you may choose from them or use some similar function. To tackle the negative range, you may add a bias of 64 to the output.

[image]

Please note that the denominator is just a constant and need not be computed. For simplicity you can just use following instead of equation 1,

`[f(x)] / [3*f(xmax)]`

In your case `xmax = 64 + bias(if you choose to use one)`

Regards.